# Import profile (birth date) from excel file to MySQL

Tags: php, import, yii2, phpexcel

I have structure table like: name varchar(15), gender smallint(1), birth_date date().

Controller:

```
public function actionImport()
{
    $profile = new Profile();

            $inputFile = 'files/profile.xlsx';
            try{
                $inputFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFile);
                $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
                $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFile);

            }catch(Exception $e){
                die('error');
            }

            $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
            $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
            $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

            for($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++)
            {
                $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A'.$row.':'.$highestColumn.$row, Null, TRUE, FALSE);

                if($row == 1){
                    continue;
                }

                $profile->name = $rowData[0][0];
                $profile->gender = $rowData[0][1];
                $profile->birth_date = $rowData[0][2];
                $profile->save();

            }

}
```

File: profile.xlsx
[image]

Data import success, but birth_date still 0000-00-00.

I try to print_r display like this:

[image]

Data saved in table like this:

[image]

Comment: have you print the rowData to verify the birthdate row?

Comment: i try to print_r, display like that image i update above.

Answer (score 0):

> Dependence of your image, you try to save int number in date 
>   field...so that the error is gone....

To resolve issue, you need to change number to date like this `Y-m-d` such as: 1991-11-20, this is MySQL date format, or you need to change MySQL field type to int if you need to save this number in database.

In PHP:

```
echo date('Y-m-d');
```

And you can convert date from unix by this:

```
    $unixtime = 1307595105;
echo $time = date("Y-m-d", $unixtime);
```

for your example:

```
$profile->birth_date = date("Y-m-d", ($rowData[0][2] - 25569) * 86400);
```

OR

```
$profile->birth_date = date('Y-m-d', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($rowData[0][2]));
```

Answer (score 0):

A `getValue()` call on a field containing a date should return a value like 41959.... that is, an MS Excel serialized datetime stamp based on the number of days since 1st January 1900 (or 1st January 1904 if the file was created using the Mac version of MS Excel), and (by default) `rangeToArray()` uses a `getValue()` call.

To get a formatted date string, you need to call `getFormattedValue()` instead; and PHPExcel then uses the number format mask for that cell to format the date according to that mask. You can set `rangeToArray()` to do this for you by setting the `$formatData` argument to true.

```
$rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A'.$row.':'.$highestColumn.$row, Null, TRUE, TRUE);
```

This will format all cells as they appear in the spreadsheet in Excel itself.

Alternatively, PHPExcel does provide functions to convert date values between Excel timestamps and unix timestamps, or PHP DateTime objects, and you could use those instead:

```
$profile->birth_date = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($rowData[0][2])
    ->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: i try this:
$profile->birth_date = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($rowData[0][2])
    ->format('Y-m-d');

but i got error:

Class 'app\controllers\PHPExcel_Shared_Date' not found

Comment: If your app is namespaced, then you'll need to ensure that you're referencing `\PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject()` in the global namespace by prefixing it with a \